# Drop Down Select File And Include It into Same Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, include

Tried to do this but it's only echoing the value not actually choosing the .php file to include into the same page. The code is below...

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="test.php">
<select name="select" onChange="document.form1.submit()">
 <option selected>Select an Industry</option>
 <option value="members">members</option>
 <option value="Female">Female Members</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

$file = $_POST['select'];
echo $file;


$path_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/$file.php;
if(file_exists($path_file))
{
  echo("The file does not exist at: $path_file");
}
else
{
  require_once($path_file);
}?>
</body>
```

Once sorted I am hoping it will include a php file into the same page! Also need  a default page before changing it, so Members be the main page, then people can select Female to see just female etc.

Comment: Are both these code blocks on the same page?

Comment: Yeah, it echo the value via echo $file; so need it to be included too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$path_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/$file.php;
```

to

```
$path_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$file.".php";
```

But this is very bad for security (you can't trust _POST data). Better change to something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['select']) && $_POST['select'])
{
if ($_POST['select'] == 'something')
 include 'something.php';
if ($_POST['select'] == 'somethingelse')
 include 'another.php';
} else {
  include 'default.php';
}
```

Comment: If $_POST['select'] is empty?  Just add 'else': if (isset($_POST['select']) && $_POST['select']) { .... } else { include 'main.php'; }

Comment: I get this mate, PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/name/public_html/test.php on line 18