# Include PHP file based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: php

I'm trying to set it up so I can include one of my PHP files based on a dropdown selection.  I found another answer on here that appears to do that but when I try it I get an error "undefined function".

The original answer is here [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050730/drop-down-select-file-and-include-it-into-same-page)

Here is my code:

```
<?php


$includes=array(
         'phpfile1'=>'phpfile1.php',
         'phpfile2'=>'phpfile2.php'
         );

if(isset($_POST['cmtype']) && array_key_exists($_POST['cmtype'], $includes)) :
    get_template_part($includes[$_POST['cmtype']]);
endif;
?>


<form id="selection_form" action="" method="post">
<select name="cmtype" id="cmtype">
<option value="default"> </option>
<option value="phpfile1">PHP file 1</option>
<option value="phpfile2">PHP File 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="select_mode_submit" value="Get File">
</form>
```

When I select either of the options and hit the button I get the error for 'get_template_part'.  I assume it has something to do with the function being in the IF statement but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Where is get_template_part() defined?

Comment: The full error would be useful

Comment: do you even have a file with this function 'get_template_part'?

Comment: But i guess the values of $includes array should be without the extension like : `'phpfile1'=>'phpfile1'` based on the documentation

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: Your `get_template_part()` function probably doesn't exist. You could replace it with `include()` if that is what you want.

Comment: Can you post the error what you are getting exactly ?

Comment: Here is the error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in E:\xampp\htdocs\tools\testfile.php on line 39

I suspect the issue is that previous answer was not complete, there is a function I need to define.

What I'm trying to do is have a drop down selection determine which php file to include.

Comment: did you add  `<?php get_header(); ?>` ? @JasonM

Comment: Are you actually using Wordpress here?  A lot of people are assuming that you are, but I don't see any evidence of it.

Comment: @PatrickQ get_template_part() is wordpress builtin function

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That doesn't mean that the OP is actually using Wordpress. As the question mentions, some of this code was taken from a different answer. A rogue editor took it upon him/herself to add the wordpress tag.

Comment: @PatrickQ well he just answered his on question below, he copied without understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
`get_template_part()
```

is WordPress built in function and is not PHP built in function. There may be a problem with you WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize "get_template_part" from that other answer is specific to wordpress, which I am not using.  So instead I tried changing it to include() instead as suggested by Bart Bergmans and that appears to work fine.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you are going to choice the file name based on the selection you have to made. But you should be clear what are you going to do after you have made the selection. In your code you have used the get_template_part() function but there is no built in function like that. If you have seen in the wordpress, you should know that the function is defined somewhere. So you should try to defined in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the include statement.

```
<?php
$includes = array(
    'foo'=>'/tmp/foo.php',
    'bar'=>'/tmp/bar.php'
);

if(
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
    && isset($_POST['cmtype'])
    && array_key_exists($_POST['cmtype'], $includes)
) {
    include $includes[$_POST['cmtype']];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="cmtype">
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Include file">
</form>
```